# Summarise Data based on an Account within a Query using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Come up against an issue where i want to summarize results in a query.

Example being as follows:

```
NAME | FRUIT | PRICE 
JOHN | APPLE |  2
JOHN | APPLE |  2
JOHN | APPLE |  2
JOHN | APPLE |  2
DAVE | GRAPE |  3
DAVE | GRAPE |  3
DAVE | GRAPE |  3
```

This is my table at the moment, what i need though is to have a summary of Johns business, like below:

```
NAME | FRUIT | PRICE 
JOHN | APPLE |  2
JOHN | APPLE |  2
JOHN | APPLE |  2
JOHN | APPLE |  2
JOHN | TOTAL |  8 
DAVE | GRAPE |  3
DAVE | GRAPE |  3
DAVE | GRAPE |  3
```

I have tried to group the information but it does not reflect what i want, plus if John were to have different fruit it would need to sum that up before it sums up the next part.

Any advice would be great

Comment: Try query below `select *
(select name, fruit + ' total', sum(price) 
from table_name 
group by name, fruit
union all
select name, fruit, price
from table_name)
order by name, fruit`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want a summary only of John?  You can use `union all` for this:

```
select name, fruit, price
from ((select name, fruit, price, 1 as ord, fruit as f
       from t
      ) union all
      (select name, 'Total', sum(price), 2 as ord, fruit as f
       from t
       where name = 'John'
       group by name, fruit
      )
     ) x
order by name, f, ord;
```

Comment: Reason would be to see a running total across all customers, there could be 40 customers in this and we would see there summaries as we go along

Comment: @nonagon . . . If that is your question, then ask *another* question.  This one is specifically about John and not Dave.  If you change the question, you will invalidate this answer, which is rude, because it could cause downvotes.

Comment: I'm asking for John as an example, the question will remain as it is

Comment: @Nonagon . . . This answers your question then.